# Is there a way to set a list from a file as a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Im struggling to get lists i have in a file as a value in a dictionary.

I have this .txt file:

```
A,['♠8', '♥9', '♥D', '♥K']
B,['♣J', '♠10', '♥J', '♦K']
C,['♣K', '♦A', '♣A']
D,['♦9', '♠J', '♥A', '♦7']
E,['♣D', '♠A', '♥8']
F,['♦J', '♠K', '♦D', '♣9']
G,['♠7', '♣8', '♠D', '♦8']
H,['♣10', '♠9', '♥10', '♦10']
```

I want the first letter to be the Key, and the following list to be the value.

```
for line in file:
        key=line[:1]
        kort[key]=line[2:-1]
```

This is how it turns out:

```
{'A': "['♠8', '♥9', '♥D', '♥K']", 'B': "['♣J', '♠10', '♥J', '♦K']", 'C': "['♣K', '♦A', '♣A']", 'D': "['♦9', '♠J', '♥A', '♦7']", 'E': "['♣D', '♠A', '♥8']", 'F': "['♦J', '♠K', '♦D', '♣9']", 'G': "['♠7', '♣8', '♠D', '♦8']", 'H': "['♣10', '♠9', '♥10', '♦10']"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to transfer the string to a list.

```
import ast
data = "['♠8', '♥9', '♥D', '♥K']"
result = ast.literal_eval(data)
print(result)
```

This gives you `['♠8', '♥9', '♥D', '♥K']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast` and `dict comprehension` to achieve it.

```
# Input
file = """A,['♠8', '♥9', '♥D', '♥K']
B,['♣J', '♠10', '♥J', '♦K']
C,['♣K', '♦A', '♣A']
D,['♦9', '♠J', '♥A', '♦7']
E,['♣D', '♠A', '♥8']
F,['♦J', '♠K', '♦D', '♣9']
G,['♠7', '♣8', '♠D', '♦8']
H,['♣10', '♠9', '♥10', '♦10']"""

# Main code
from ast import literal_eval as le
res = {line.split(",",1)[0]: le(line.split(",",1)[1]) for line in file.split("\n")}

# Output
print (res)

# {'A': ['♠8', '♥9', '♥D', '♥K'], 'B': ['♣J', '♠10', '♥J', '♦K'], 'C': ['♣K', '♦A', '♣A'], 'D': ['♦9', '♠J', '♥A', '♦7'], 'E': ['♣D', '♠A', '♥8'], 'F': ['♦J', '♠K', '♦D', '♣9'], 'G': ['♠7', '♣8', '♠D', '♦8'], 'H': ['♣10', '♠9', '♥10', '♦10']}
```

I hope this helps and counts!

Comment: I thought about a dictionary comprehension too, but I didn't like the fact that you have to split two times.

Comment: Yes, You are right!, I used dict comprehension considering the data set to be very small. If the data set is huge definitely we should go for a simple for loop.